# How can I remove borders around images on Blogger?

Tags: html, css, border

Hi can someone teach me how to remove the white borders around an image posted on a Blogger blog?

This is the blog link: www.ulimali.blogspot.com

Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow/html/css, I would really appreciate it if someone can help me with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to remove the border as well as the shadow behind. For that use this CSS:

```
img {
padding: 0 !important;
border: none !important;
background: none !important;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent !important;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: Add 'outline:0;' to your img styles as well - this will remove any dotted outlines on image links.  See this article for reference: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/outline/